# R write mpfr data (Rmpfr)

Tags: r, writetofile, mpfr

I'm have a mpfrArray in R that I am trying to write to file but I get the error message:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("mpfr1", package = "Rmpfr")" to a data.frame
```

How would I go about writing the mpfrArray to file?

Example:

```
library(Rmpfr)
a<-mpfrArray(1:9, precBits=113, dim=c(3,3))
write.table(a,'a')
```

Comment: Include your code please, the error message is not sufficient information by itself.

Comment: @nrussell I edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First coerce the `mpfrArray` to a regular matrix

```
matrix(as.numeric(a), nrow = dim(a)[1], ncol = dim(a)[2])
```